CSV imports are not idempotent for tags
When I import a CSV file with values, including component GUIDs, (under Publish->Model Exchange->CSV->CSV Import/Export) I want them to replace existing values, if any. Unfortunately, this does not happen for tags, which instead adds imported tag values to existing ones, thereby creating lists. So if I run my CSV import 10 times, 10 identical list items are added to a component's tag. In the GUI, these can be viewed by setting the "Show Duplicate Tags" property to true. If false, only the first list item value is shown.
I am using version 16.1.1625.
How can I get the desired idempotent behavior? I've studied online resources which indicate that it may be necessary to create scripts or SQL statements to rectify this, but I'd rather not.

Have you looked into Geert's importer? (seems he's on holiday righr now)

@qwerty_so: Thanks for the tip, I'll check it out.
